# How to add different animation using animate.css on clicking custom previous and next button - OwlCarousel

Tags: jquery

Im using animate.css for custom animation on Owl Carousel. while using this its animating the same when I click on the next and previous button. I need the animation different. How to call different animation on clicking on custom next and previous buttons. Please help.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:1,
            loop:false,
            center:true,
            margin:10,
            URLhashListener:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
            animateIn: 'slideInUp',
            startPosition: 'URLHash'
        });

var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();  
$('.nextOwl').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})

$('.prevOwl').click(function() {
    owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
    // here I would like to change the animateOut and animateIn to slideOutDown

});
```

Comment: $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   items:1,
   loop:false,
   center:true,
   margin:10,
   URLhashListener:true,
   autoplayHoverPause:true,
   animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
   animateIn: 'slideInUp',
   startPosition: 'URLHash'
  });

need to change the animateOut and Animate in different animation when I click on next button.

Comment: Hi Biju, you can use the edit button to update your answer.